# Possible to add imagick webp support for PHP in AWS Linux 2?

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, webp, php-7.4, amazon-linux-2

I'm running PHP 7.4 on an AWS Linux 2 instance. PHP 7.4 comes with imagick module 3.4.4 compiled by ImageMagick 6.9.10-6, but it doesn't have support for WEBP enabled.

I've installed the `libwebp-devel` library, but I can't figure out how to recompile the imagick module to support webp. I tried installing from the PECL source a la [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31679858/338801), but when I check `php -i` WEBP still isn't listed under supported formats.

I also tried installing ImageMagick from source, and while I was able to get WEBP conversion going in the command line, the PHP extension still doesn't show support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not currently expert at PHP, but after reading this post [Understanding PHP library installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401907/understanding-php-library-installation) and knowing some linux ecosystem, I think that after recompiling ImageMagick, you have to tell to the imagick module, that you have new version of ImageMagick. Or even recompile module (according to this site: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/217253537-Installing-ImageMagick-and-the-imagick-PHP-module-on-Shared-hosting).